# AngularJs - Reference the same scope property from multiple ngRepeat's

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have multiple `ngRepeats` generate table contents, depending on the view the user wants to see, a different `ngRepeat` is used to generate the table. When the user switches their view, and one of the following is removed from the DOM and another added, the new `ngRepeat` does not reference to the same `pagination.filteredData` array.

**Example:** `Main` is my controller, using `controller as` syntax.

```
<tr ng-if="Main.tableConfig.programGranularity == 'overall'" ng-repeat="item in Main.pagination.filteredData = ( Main.data.overallData | filterByDateRange | filter: Main.tableConfig.generalSearch | orderBy: ['Date', 'Name']) | startFrom: Main.pagination.startAtIndex | limitTo: Main.pagination.pageSize">
    <td ng-repeat="column in Main.tableConfig.columnsConfig | selectColumnsByGranularity: Main.tableConfig.programGranularity">
        <span ng-if="!column.isDate" ng-bind="item[column.dataValue] | ifEmpty: 0"></span>
        <span ng-if="column.isDate" ng-bind="item[column.dataValue] | date:'MM/dd/yyyy': 'UTC' | ifEmpty: 0"></span>
    </td>
</tr>

<tr ng-if="Main.tableConfig.programGranularity == 'team'" ng-repeat="item in Main.pagination.filteredData = ( Main.data.teamData | filterByDateRange | filter: Main.tableConfig.generalSearch | orderBy: ['Date', 'Name']) | startFrom: Main.pagination.startAtIndex | limitTo: Main.pagination.pageSize">
    <td ng-repeat="column in Main.tableConfig.columnsConfig | selectColumnsByGranularity: Main.tableConfig.programGranularity">
        <span ng-if="!column.isDate" ng-bind="item[column.dataValue] | ifEmpty: 0"></span>
        <span ng-if="column.isDate" ng-bind="item[column.dataValue] | date:'MM/dd/yyyy': 'UTC' | ifEmpty: 0"></span>
    </td>
</tr>

<tr ng-if="Main.tableConfig.programGranularity == 'colleague'" ng-repeat="item in Main.pagination.filteredData = ( Main.data.parsedData | filterByDateRange | filter: Main.tableConfig.generalSearch | orderBy: ['Date', 'Name']) | startFrom: Main.pagination.startAtIndex | limitTo: Main.pagination.pageSize">
    <td ng-repeat="column in Main.tableConfig.columnsConfig | selectColumnsByGranularity: Main.tableConfig.programGranularity">
        <span ng-if="!column.isDate" ng-bind="item[column.dataValue] | ifEmpty: 0"></span>
        <span ng-if="column.isDate" ng-bind="item[column.dataValue] | date:'MM/dd/yyyy': 'UTC' | ifEmpty: 0"></span>
    </td>
</tr>
```

I want the same `pagination.filteredData` array to be set by each of the `ngRepeat` directives. However, only the first `ngRepeat` that runs sets the value and no other `ngRepeat` will set it again.

I've tried `ngInit` and initializing an object with `pagination` inside of it, and referencing that in my `ngRepeat`. I have also tried using `$parent.pagination.filteredData`.

Using **AngularJS v1.5.0**

How do I get this to work?

Similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38235907/angularjs-service-variable-not-being-set-inside-of-ngrepeat but reworded and fundamentally different. Solving the same problem though.

**Edit:** Refactored to utilize the `controller as` syntax, the problem still persists. To me it seems that when I switch to a different ngRepeat, a new array and reference is created, instead of overwriting the current arrays values.

Comment: I see this issue almost every day on SO in the angular tag. You need to use angular's "controller as" syntax, which allows you to be unambiguous about which scope you are using in your views. Here is a fantastic article I always link to that explains this very well: https://toddmotto.com/digging-into-angulars-controller-as-syntax/

Comment: Have you tried `ng-init="pagination.startAtIndex = 0"`?

Comment: You could filter the data manually in the controller by injecting `$filter`, set the result on your service property, and then have your ng-repeat iterate over the pre-filtered results.

Comment: @AlonEitan The `startAtIndex` and `pageSize` are referenced correctly, and work between all ngRepeats. However, I did that for kicks and it did not change the behavior I am having issues with.

Comment: @mhodges After refactoring to utilize the controller as syntax (Great link by the way), the problem still persists. Even when referencing to an object in my new controller, only the first ngRepeats values stick.

Comment: @DouglasGaskell Correct me if I'm wrong, but when you refactored to use the "controller as" syntax, you changed pagination.filteredData to Main.filteredData, but you kept Main.pagination.startAtIndex, and Main.pagination.pageSize, etc. around. Should you be referencing Main.pagination.filteredData?

Comment: @mhodges Woops, I just copy/pasted the wrong chunk of HTML. That was me testing if just sticking an object into my `Main` class would behave any differently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I have spent some time putting together a [demo replicating (as best I could) the code that you have provided](http://jsbin.com/fujibiz/3/edit?html,js,output) **<-- Broken**, and I think I understand your issue. You say "the first ng-repeat that runs sets the value", and I think it's actually the **LAST** ng-repeat that runs that is setting it. It's not having a problem setting the value, the problem is that all 3 ng-repeats run every time, so it's always the last one that wins.

> The reason this happens is because ng-repeat executes **BEFORE** ng-if for the common case of `<element ng-if="item.showMe" ng-repeat="item in Main.items"></element>`

That being said, even though your `ng-if` condition is false, so the `<tr>` does not get displayed, the `ng-repeat` has already run, and already set `Main.pagination.filteredData`

**I think your best course of action would be to move your `ng-if` up one level to the `<tbody>`.** It would look like the following:

[WORKING DEMO](http://jsbin.com/fujibiz/2/edit?html,js,output) **<-- Working**

```
<table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Data</th>
        <th>Date</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody ng-if="Main.tableConfig.programGranularity == 'overall'" >
      <tr ng-repeat="item in Main.pagination.filteredData = (Main.data.overallData | filterByDateRange | orderBy: ['date', 'name']) | startFrom: Main.pagination.startAtIndex | limitTo: Main.pagination.pageSize">
        <td ng-bind="item.name"></td>
        <td ng-bind="item.overall"></td>
        <td ng-bind="item.date"></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody ng-if="Main.tableConfig.programGranularity == 'team'" >
      <tr ng-repeat="item in Main.pagination.filteredData = (Main.data.teamData | filterByDateRange | orderBy: ['date', 'name']) | startFrom: Main.pagination.startAtIndex | limitTo: Main.pagination.pageSize">
        <td ng-bind="item.name"></td>
        <td ng-bind="item.team"></td>
        <td ng-bind="item.date"></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: That's a brilliant observation, thank you! Did you find documentation for this behavior, or puzzle it out on your own? I probably would have never considered that.

After some thought you are correct in that the last ng-repeat that runs sets it. Assuming they run in the order they are in the markup, the last one (colleagues) is what the filtered array is always set to.

Comment: @DouglasGaskell You're welcome! Honestly, creating the demo to isolate the behavior and displaying the value of Main.pagination.filteredData really helped. I could see that it was always getting set to the last list, and while trying to figure out why, I remembered that ng-repeat ran before ng-if because I utilize that functionality all the time. The most logical solution from there was just to move it up to the <tbody> so that the ng-repeat did not run if the ng-if was false, and problem solved!

Comment: @DouglasGaskell Also, I am glad that you refactored to use "controller as". Even though it was not the direct solution to your issue, I think it will prove to be helpful in the long run. It's a shame that more people don't know about it, because it really is the best way to implement controllers in your views (for the various reasons listed in the article).

Comment: I agree, the "controller as" is much more logical when it comes to referencing nested controllers in your HTML. You definitely avoid $scope hell. It's also necessary if I plan on migrating to Angular 2 in the future.